# PHP: Handle unknown results of API request

Tags: php, api

I would like to solve the following problem:

I'm calling a SOAP-API and try to handle the answers in a way that allows me to determine if an object exists on the target-server or not.

I got `ContactGet`, `CustomerGet` and `UserGet`.

If `ContactGet` matches a contact the answer looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)#394 (12) { ["type"]=> int(0) ["salutation"]=> int(0) ["firstname"]=> string(4) "Test" ["lastname"]=> string(4) "Test" ["address1"]=> string(12) "Teststreet 3" ["zipcode"]=> string(5) "12345" ["city"]=> string(8) "Testcity" ["country"]=> string(2) "DE" ["phone"]=> string(14) "+4912345678910" ["fax"]=> string(14) "+ 4912345678911" ["mobile"]=> string(14) "+ 4912345678913" ["email"]=> string(16) "test@example.com" }
```

if `ContactGet` is *empty* the answer looks like this:

```
bool(false)
```

If I'm using `CustomerGet`and having a *positive match* the output is the following:

```
object(stdClass)#401 (1) { ["CustomerDetails"]=> object(stdClass)#387 (6) { ["id"]=> string(12) "cB-pUbAED.ca" ["cid"]=> int(76) ["owner_c"]=> string(12) "cL2AmcgAdSMa" ["admin_c"]=> string(12) "cL2AmcgAdSMa" ["billing_c"]=> string(12) "cL2AmcgAdSMa" ["locked"]=> int(0) } }
```

If the `customer` does *not exist* the answer is the following:

```
object(stdClass)#398 (1) { ["customers"]=> object(stdClass)#401 (0) { } }
```

Same is on `UserGet`:

```
object(stdClass)#409 (1) { ["users"]=> object(stdClass)#412 (0) { } }
```

means that there is no such user.

Now I wanted to have a function which does not care which type of handle I'm checking:

The function calls the getXXXX-function on target server and returns the result.

My question is: If I do not know which return I have to expect, how can I return "true" or "false" if `ContactGet`, `CustomerGet` or `UserGet` is empty? The returns of these API-calls are different, so I do not know how to generally handle it.

I tried to solve the problem by accessing the first object with

```
count(current((Array)$result)
```

But this is always int(1).

Comment: Please show the posative outcomes as well as the negative. The answer is going to be a couple of if statements, with calls to `is_bool`, `empty` etc. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my question now.

Comment: i believe my answer will prove helpful. Just go with a function that handles each "error" call seperately and unifies it on your code

Answer (score 0):

return true on error, false on not error;

```
is_error($message)
{
if(empty($message)) return true;
if(isset($message->customers) && empty($message->customers) ) return true;
if(isset($message->users) && empty($message->users) ) return true;
return false;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$message = call_to_get_message();
if(is_error($message))
{
//handle the error
}
else
{
//proceed
}
```